# How to fill NSGridView by cell by cell or by row?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I make an outlet from XCode(btw I make a Mac App if it's important). And I tried to fill a Grid like a second dimension array. It would be perfect. But I only found a two methods `AddRow()` and `AddColumn()` but either of them is should be filled by `NSView[]` array. Which I don't how to make of strings values for example.

Comment: You need to create a NSGridCell for each cell within your grid view that contains a perhaps an NSTextView that is assigned a value from your array. (Maybe a NSTableView would be more of a fit then NSGridView since you can assign a data source )

Comment: @SushiHangover I don't find a method which can add `NSGridCell` to `NSGridView`

Comment: @SushiHangover and in NSTableView the same problem. I don't find a method which accepts an array of `NSTextView` or similar.

Comment: Anybody? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add controls in NSGridView instead of plain text. For example, if you want to show a set of strings you could use NSTextField:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    stringList.Add("string" + i);
}

NSGridView gridView = new NSGridView();
gridView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

foreach (var str in stringList)
{
    var rowList = new List<NSTextField> { new NSTextField { StringValue = str, Editable = false } };
    gridView.AddRow(rowList.ToArray());
}

View.AddSubview(gridView);
```

Comment: I did like you wrote. But still, nothing appears. Maybe `NSGridView` need some enable or something.

Comment: If in the XCode UI builder's you don't set rows and columns(I mean it's set by default). But I need to add them dynamically. Is there a way to do this? I think now it does not appear cause of this problem. Or does it matter if ur WindowView maybe smaller than GridView size?

Comment: I'm also having problems with this but I'm trying to dynamically place buttons in the grid view.  Th buttons appear but don't respond to key clicks.  Any suggestions on where to look.